# What is a basis (not necessarily orthogonal) of Herm(A) consisting of pure density matrices in D(A)?($A \cong \mathbb{C}^{n}$)

Tags: quantum-state, textbook-and-exercises

Let $A \cong \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a Hilbert space $A,$ and let $\operatorname{Herm}(A)$ be the Hilbert space consisting of all Hermitian matrices on $A$. Give an example of a basis (not necessarily orthogonal) of Herm (A) consisting of pure density matrices in $\mathfrak{D}(A)$.

$\mathbf A\mathbf t\mathbf t\mathbf e\mathbf m\mathbf p\mathbf t$:

I Started with the case $n=2$ and considered the vectors $|0\rangle,|1\rangle,|+\rangle$ and $|+i\rangle$ , Because I think $\left|0\right\rangle\left\langle 0\right|$, $\left|1\right\rangle\left\langle 1\right|$, $\left|+\right\rangle\left\langle +\right|$, and $\left|+i\right\rangle\left\langle +i\right|$ are a non-orthogonal basis and all of them are pure density matrices. And as you know,

$|+\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)$

$|+i\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0\rangle+i|1\rangle)$.

But my question is how can I prove or show that they are form a basis for $\operatorname{Herm}(A)$, in this case $A \cong \mathbb{C}^{2}$ and how can I expand it to $A \cong \mathbb{C}^{n}$? I mean how can I determine a basis for $A \cong \mathbb{C}^{n}$ which are pure density matrices and how can I show that it is a basis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $ n = 2 $, it is known that the Pauli matrices together with the identity matrix $ I $ form a basis.
Now observe that we can write:

- $ I = |0 \rangle \langle 0| + |1 \rangle \langle 1| $
- $ \sigma_z  = 2 \cdot |0  \rangle \langle  0| - I $
- $ \sigma_x  = 2 \cdot |+  \rangle \langle  +| - I $
- $ \sigma_y  = 2 \cdot |+i \rangle \langle +i| - I $

This means that also the pure density matrices
$|0 \rangle \langle 0|, \hspace{0.3em}
 |1 \rangle \langle 1|, \hspace{0.3em} 
 |+ \rangle \langle +|, \hspace{0.3em} 
 |+i \rangle \langle +i|  $ are a basis (not orthogonal).

For the general case, the matrices $ H_{a,b} $, with $ 1 \leq a,b \leq n $, form an orthogonal basis for Herm$(A)$ (see section [1.4.2](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ewatrous/LectureNotes/CS766.Fall2011/01.pdf))
$$
\
  H_{a,b} =
  \begin{cases}
       E_{a,a} & \text{if $a = b $} \\
       E_{a,b} + E_{b,a} & \text{if $a < b$} \\
       i (E_{a,b} - E_{b,a}) & \text{if $a > b$}
  \end{cases}
\
$$
where $ E_{a,b} = |e_a \rangle \langle e_b| $ and $ |e_a \rangle $ a state with 1 in the $a$-th entry and all other entries zeros.

Now define the states:
$$
\
  |\psi_{a,b} \rangle =
  \begin{cases}
       |e_a \rangle & \text{if $a = b $} \\
       \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (|e_a \rangle + |e_b \rangle) & \text{if $a < b$} \\
       \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} (i|e_a \rangle + |e_b \rangle) & \text{if $a > b$}
  \end{cases}
\
$$
and the pure density matrices $ \rho_{a,b} = |\psi_{a,b} \rangle \langle \psi_{a,b}| $. After some calculations we get

- $ H_{a, a} = \rho_{a,a} $
- $ H_{a, b} = 2 \rho_{a,b} - \rho_{a,a} - \rho_{b,b} $

so $ \rho_{a,b} $ form a basis.

Comment: Neat answer! Is there some intuition/proof for why $H_{a,b}$ form a basis for all Hermitian operators? The result is stated without proof in Watrous' notes

Comment: I think that you should be able to verify that $ M = \sum_{a=1}^{n} m_{aa} H_{a,a} + \sum_{a < b} Re\{ m_{ab} \} H_{a,b} + \sum_{a > b} Im\{ m_{ab} \} H_{a,b} $ for any Hermitian matrix $ M = [m_{ab}] $

Answer (score 1):

*I will **try** to take a stab at it from my understanding of your question:*

The basis for the space of $2 \times 2$ Hermitian matrices over $\mathbb{R}$ is:

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & i\\ -i & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

But from my understanding, you want to restrict the basis set  to consist of only rank 1 matrices. Is that right? You are considering the basis set

\begin{equation}
|0\rangle\langle 0| = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ |1\rangle\langle 1| = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ |+\rangle\langle +| =\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1\\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \ \ \ \ |i\rangle\langle i| =\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i\\ i & 1 \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Well, if we take $H$ to be the Hermitian matrix

$$ H = \dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & i\\ -i & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Can you form this Hermitian matrix $H$ from your supposedly basis set?

---

**update:** As commented, I made a wrong calculation, as $|i\rangle \langle i|$ should be

$$
|i\rangle\langle i| =\dfrac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -i\\ i & 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
and therefore it can be written as $H = \dfrac{1}{2}|0\rangle\langle 0| + \dfrac{1}{2}|1\rangle\langle 1| - |i\rangle\langle i | $

And it turns out that the basis set in consideration is actually correct as now pointed out by the other answer! Thanks for bringing up this problem though.

Comment: Yes, maybe you are right and my attempt is wrong, but the hint of the problem says that we can use the $|0\rangle,|1\rangle,|+\rangle$ and $|+i\rangle$ to form new basis which are pure density matrices(Positive semi-definite with rank 1).

Comment: The $H$ you give there is just $-|+\! i \rangle\langle +i|$, so not a good "counterexample".